# Function properties in TypeScript class not recognzied

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a TypeScript class that has an optional property of type function. This property has a default implementation but a new object when constructing can override the default implementation for this function property.

For example

```js
export class MyObj {
  public props: MyObjProps;

  constructor({
    title,
    isHidden = false,
    format = (val) => val,
  }: MyObjProps) {
    this.props = arguments[0];
  }
}

interface MyObjProps {
  title: string;
  isHidden?: boolean;
  format?: (val: string) => string;
}
```

Then if I create an instance

```js
const myObj = new MyObj({
  title: "Blah", 
  format: (val) => "custom: " + val
});
```

and I do `myObj.props.format("something")` instead of getting `custom: something` it says `format is not a function`.

What on earth is happening? I don't get why it doesn't work. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need adapt the code like that

```
interface MyObjProps {
  title: string;
  format?: (val: string) => string;
}

class MyObj {
  public props: MyObjProps;

  constructor(x: MyObjProps) {
    this.props = x;
  }
}



const myObj = new MyObj({
  title: "Blah", 
  format: (val: string) => "custom: " + val
});

var y = myObj.props.format("123");
console.log(y);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. unfortunately i cannot do that as i need the default value for property isHidden.